# datagridview show back a row after hided

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a checkbox to hide if the row is certain color,

```
private void filter_color_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow item in mproductDataGridView.Rows)
    {
        if(item.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor != Color.Yellow)
        {
            CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[mproductDataGridView.DataSource];
            currencyManager1.SuspendBinding();
            item.Visible = false;
            currencyManager1.ResumeBinding();

        } else
        {
            CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[mproductDataGridView.DataSource];
            currencyManager1.SuspendBinding();
            item.Visible = true;
            currencyManager1.ResumeBinding();
        }
    }
}
```

The above function is work only "item.Visible = false;", i want to show back the hided rows after uncheck the checkbox, the code after else { is not working, anyonw knows how to do that?

Comment: Can you change `CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[mproductDataGridView.DataSource];` to `CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)mproductDataGridView.BindingContext[mproductDataGridView.DataSource];`

Comment: changed, the result is same

Comment: seems the color is still yellow, so i can't unhide

Comment: @hkguile I think you should decide this on the data level. Which value of your DataSource decide the color of your row? If you know this you easily can create a new DataSource without this values (for hiding) and adding them if you want to make it visible again.

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (!checkBox1.Checked)
                {
                    CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
                    currencyManager1.SuspendBinding();
                    item.Visible = dataGridView1.Rows[item.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                    currencyManager1.ResumeBinding();

                }
                else
                {
                    CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[dataGridView1.DataSource];
                    currencyManager1.SuspendBinding();
                    item.Visible = true;
                    currencyManager1.ResumeBinding();
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers correctly point out you are not checking to see if the check box is checked. Using the check box as a toggle, I separated the filter and un-filter logic with two methods.

```
private void filter_color_CheckedChanged2(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  CurrencyManager currencyManager1 = (CurrencyManager)BindingContext[mproductDataGridView.DataSource];
  currencyManager1.SuspendBinding();
  if (filter_color.Checked)
    FilterRows(Color.Yellow);
  else
    UnFilterRows();
  currencyManager1.ResumeBinding();
}

private void FilterRows(Color fColor) {
  foreach (DataGridViewRow item in mproductDataGridView.Rows) {
    if (!item.IsNewRow) {
      if (item.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor != fColor) {
        item.Visible = false;
      }
    }
  }
}

private void UnFilterRows() {
  foreach (DataGridViewRow item in mproductDataGridView.Rows) {
    item.Visible = true;
  }
}
```